# Inner Exception in Dart Future not getting caught

Tags: dart

I'm new working with Flutter 1.0 and Dart 2.0, and there is something I'm not understanding about error handling in Futures (have read through [futures error handling](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/libraries/futures-error-handling)).

This code does not catch and an exception thrown from inside the stack:

```
_userRepository.loginWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
.then((user) {
  print(user.id);
  print(user.toString());
}).catchError((err) {
  print(err.toString());
});
```

Inside _userRepository:

```
@override
  Future<UserEntity> loginWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password) {
    return new Future(() {
      return auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password)
      .then((user) {
        return UserEntity(
          user.uid,
          user.displayName,
          user.email,
          emailVerified: user.isEmailVerified,
          isAnonymous: user.isAnonymous,
          phoneNumber: user.phoneNumber,
          photoUrl: user.photoUrl,
          created: user.metadata.creationTimestamp,
          lastSignIn: user.metadata.lastSignInTimestamp
        );
      });
   });
  }
```

`auth` is the FirebaseAuth package. `signInWithEmailAndPassword` returns a `Future<FirebaseUser>`. That call is working correctly. The password is empty in my test, and FirebaseAuth is returning an error to dart/flutter: "Given String is empty or null". Flutter is throwing the error from message_codecs.dart at this line:

```
throw PlatformException(code: errorCode, message: errorMessage, details: errorDetails);
```

All of that is working as expected, but I don't understand why the .catchError is not catching the exception. `loginWithEmailAndPassword` is wrapping the code block in a `new Future()`. I've also tried `new Future.sync()` and tried not wrapping the code block and instead just returning `return auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword.then(...);`.

From my reading, I'm guessing the problem is that the Platform Exception in the Flutter service code is synchronous. But I also thought that wrapping it in a Future.sync() would solve this problem. I'm guessing I could wrap it in a try/catch and await the auth.signIn... call, but I thought the Futures API would work and allow the exception to bubble up to the .catchError where I would like to deal with it.

Comment: Handling async exceptions is easier if you use `async`/`await` with `try`/`catch` than with `onError` or `catchError`

Comment: Thank you, @günter-zöchbauer. I was able to move forward by switching out to async / await and try / catch. So that's good. At some point though I'd like to understand why my implementation of a Future isn't correct using then / catchError. I do come from a javascript and Promises world where my implementation above would have worked using `return auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword()`. It could be that it's all spelled out in the [documentation](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/libraries/futures-error-handling) but I'm not getting it. If you know of a better doc, please let me know.

Comment: I'm not aware of good docs about async error handling with `onError` and `catchError` but haven't looked since years.